# Index enters the For Loop despite exceeding the upper limit

Tags: vba, loops

I can't figure out why is the index of my For-Loop entering the loop, despite its value exceeding the upper limit. Please see the pic attached below for clarity.

```
Dim cnt
cnt = 0  
Debug.Print "Total File Count before entering loop: " & xFolder.Files.Count

For Each oxFile In xFolder.Files
    If Left(oxFile.Name, 1) <> "~" And LCase(oxFile.Name) <> "thumbs.db" Then
        cnt = cnt + 1
        Debug.Print "Files processed in each iteration:" & cnt
        Call FixFileNames(oxFile)  'This sub merely shortens the file name.
    End If
Next oxFile


Private Sub FixFileNames(ByRef myFile As Object)
    Dim PrevName As String
    PrevName = myFile.Name
    PrevName = Trim(Replace(PrevName, "_XXXXX_", "", 1)
    myFile.Name = PrevName
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If you're altering the files in that folder while looping over them then that could be part of the problem you're seeing.  What do you see if you comment out the call to `FixFileNames` ?

Comment: If I comment out the call, it is coming correct. I will update my question with the code in the Sub `FixFilenames`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect all the files before processing them, so there's no chance you'll pick up any new files.

Eg:

```vb
Dim cnt, col As New Collection
  
For Each oxFile In xFolder.Files 'collect the files first
    col.Add oxFile
Next oxFile

Debug.Print "Total File Count before entering loop: " & col.Count
cnt = 0
For Each oxFile In col
    If Left(oxFile.Name, 1) <> "~" And LCase(oxFile.Name) <> "thumbs.db" Then
        cnt = cnt + 1
        Debug.Print cnt, oxFile.Name
        FixFileNames oxFile  'Call is deprecated...
    End If
Next oxFile
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. That worked. But could u explain why changing file names screwed up things. The file modified date remains the same after changing the names. Also nowhere in my code, I am saving the files.

Comment: Sorry I can't really explain it - I just have that kind of loop in my head as one to avoid.